# Issue with strcmp function in cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, matrix

I am using cell array **a** with value like below

`a = {'one' , 'two' ; 'four','five'};`

now I am just compare the **a** with some string like **'two'** and after then i just add another one column in **a** and insert string in that place

```
a{strcmp(a,'two'),3} ='Three' ;
```

I am getting output like below

```
 a = 

     'one'     'two'          []
     'four'    'five'         []
         []        []    'Three'
```

but actually I want output like below

```
 a = 

     'one'     'two'     'Three'
     'four'    'five'         []
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you get if you just type `strcmp(a,'two')` in the command line? Hint: read up on [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) and also try the results of `for ii = 1:4 disp(a{ii}) end`

Comment: i am getting like this  **strcmp(a,'two') = [    0     1;     0     0] ; **

Comment: oh I thought you'd get `3`, but forgot you'd need to call `find` first for that

Comment: So are you just trying to find which row matches your search string? In that case try `find(any(strcmp(a,'two'),2))`

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [**maps**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) for your task?

```
%// create map
keySet =   {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six','seven','eight'};
valueSet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8];
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);

%// data
a = {'one' , 'two' ; 'four', 'five'};

%// analyze data
Nums = cell2mat(values(mapObj,a));

%// expand data
Nums(:,3) = Nums(:,2) + 1

%// output
output = keySet(Nums)
```

---

```
output = 

    'one'     'two'     'three'
    'four'    'five'    'six'
```